# angularjs input trim is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Any idea why native javascript trim() function doesn't work with angularjs?

```
<input ng-model="myInput">

if($scope.myInput.trim() != ''){
alert('required');
return false;
}
```

Comment: just check if the trim fn works outside your if statement, may be your if condition always evaluates to false

Comment: you can also use this check here..https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the [`trim()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) function but , if you are checking for an empty string, it should be

```
   $scope.login = function () {       
    if($scope.myInput.trim() == ''){
     alert('required');
      }
    };
```

Working [`App`](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/5qvrk3ne/4/)